# Azure cloud service dns lookup failed

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I am tring to create my first azure cloud service with Asp.net MVC as web role using .net 4.5.2. It is running fine locally with my self signed certificate. But when I deploy it on cloud and access it I get following response.

*DNS Lookup for "necrmtest.cloudapp.net" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found*

Then I RDP to VM (hosting the web app) and try to run the web app locally there, every thing is working fine there with warning as my certificate is self signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that necrmtest.cloudapp.net resolves to 0.0.0.0 at the moment which means that you have a cloud service but no active deployment.  Have you stopped the cloud service?

The .NET exception, where is that being seen?  Is it on a client machine or inside the VM of the web role itself?  From the same machine as you're seeing that error on, can you do the following and share output:
1. nslookup necrmtest.cloudapp.net.
2. nslookup portal.azure.com.

Gareth [MSFT]